# How to properly compare 2 strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am absolutely new in JavaScript and I have a problem comparing 2 strings.

Into a function I have this code:

```
var selectedProjectStatusText = selectedProjectStatus.options[selectedProjectStatus.selectedIndex].text;

alert("== " + selectedProjectStatusText == "-- Please Select --");
alert("=== " + selectedProjectStatusText === "-- Please Select --");
```

I am using the `alert()` function to try how to work string comparator.

The problem is that both the `alert()` say me FALSE when the `selectedProjectStatusText` variable contains the `-- Please Select --` string.

Why? What am I missing? what could be the cause of the problem? How can I fix it? What am I missing?

Comment: You mentioned *contains*, are you looking for a substring?

Comment: A text with "== " at the beginning is always different to a text with "--" at the beginning

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`; it's much more comfortable in most cases.

Comment: As a good advice, don't use alert() for debugging prupose, you should use instead (without string concatenation): `console.log("=== " , selectedProjectStatusText === "-- Please Select --");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting your condition in parentheses so that it's evaluated before string concatenation.

```js
var selectedProjectStatusText = "-- Please Select --";    

alert("== " + (selectedProjectStatusText == "-- Please Select --"));
alert("=== " + (selectedProjectStatusText === "-- Please Select --"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove `"=== " +` from the start of your conditional statement, or wrap in parenthesis `"=== " + (condition)` try this instead:

```
alert(selectedProjectStatusText == "-- Please Select --");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eceb5bpx/

If you are wanting to see if the string `contains` '-- Please Select --' then your condition is incorrect and you should instead use

```
alert(string.indexOf('-- Please Select --') > -1);
```

Comment: Right, because the `+` operator is left-associative. Alternatively the right side (the comparison) could be explicitly parenthesized.

Comment: And using `console.log()` would allow to see both results without using the mouse.

Comment: Removing '=== ' isn't needed, especially if it is required text in the output. Rather parenthesis is required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JS [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) function to display the results of your comparison in the format you are using:

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angrybird/eceb5bpx/1/)

```
var selectedProjectStatusText = "-- Please Select --";
alert("== ".concat(selectedProjectStatusText == "-- Please Select --"));
alert("=== ".concat(selectedProjectStatusText === "-- Please Select --"));
```

"==" : equal to, while
"===" : equal value and equal type